# Why does $\left|\frac{\sin(n+1)}{2^{n+1}}+...+\frac{\sin(n+p)}{2^{n+p}}\right|\leq\frac{|\sin(n+1)|}{2^{n+1}}+...+\frac{|\sin(n+p)|}{2^{n+p}}$ hold?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality, triangle-inequality

I trying to understand a  proof (using Cauchy's general criterion of convergence) of why the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin (n)}{2^{n}}$ converges .
At the beginning, the following inequality is expressed:
$$\left | \frac{\sin (n+1)}{2^{n+1}}+...+\frac{\sin (n+p)}{2^{n+p}} \right |\leq \frac{|\sin (n+1)|}{2^{n+1}}+...+
\frac{|\sin (n+p)|}{2^{n+p}}$$ where $n,p$ are natural numbers.

Why does this hold? Is the triangle inequality with more than 2 terms on $\mathbb{R}$ a valid fact (from what seems to be the case here) ?

Comment: Yes, $|x_1+x_2+...+x_n| \leq |x_1|+|x_2|+...+|x_n|$ for al real (or complex) $x_1,x_2,..,x_n$.

Comment: See e.g. the “generalization” in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleInequality.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can deduce the three-term version by using the two-term version twice:

$$|x+y+z|\leq |x+y|+|z|\leq |x|+|y|+|z|$$

and you can similarly prove it for any number of terms by induction.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use geometric sums:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\sin n}{2^n}=\text{Im}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{e^i}{2}\right)^n = \text{Im}\left[\frac{e^i}{2-e^i}\left(1-\frac{e^{Ni}}{2^N}\right)\right]$$
and since $\frac{e^{Ni}}{2^N}\to 0$ as $N\to +\infty$,
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin n}{2^n}=\text{Im}\left(\frac{e^i}{2-e^i}\right)=\text{Im}\left(\frac{e^i(2-e^{-i})}{(2-e^i)(2-e^{-i})}\right)=\frac{2\sin(1)}{5-4\cos(1)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\left | \frac{\sin n }{2^n} \right |\leq \left |\frac{1}{2^n} \right |$

We know $ \sum \frac{1}{2^n} $ is Geometric series  with common ratio $\frac{1}{2}$ **convergent series**

By comparison  the given series is also convergent